# Qt on embedded system lost focus when move away mouse

Tags: qt, embedded-linux

I have a simple Qt application. There is a `QPushButton` on the `QMainWindow`; when the button is clicked, a `QDialog` with `QLineEdit` will be show (using `exec()`). The `QLineEdit` gets the focus automatically; it blinks.  When run it on my pc/Linux platform it works well.

But when I run it on embedded platform and move the cursor away from the `QDialog` widget (e.g move the cursor over the  `QMainWindow`), the dialog loses the focus: the `QLineEdit` stops blinking.

How does this happen, and how to fix it?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), 
ui(new Ui::MainWindow) 
{ 
ui->setupUi(this); 
QWidget* widgetb = new QWidget(this);//this works well 
QWidget* widgeta = new QWidget();//this will make focus follow the mouse  
QDialog* dialog = new QDialog(this);//this will make focus follow the mouse 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the way the window manager has been configured on the embedded system?  Having input focus follow the mouse pointer isn't *that* unusual.

Comment: do you mean the focus will follow the mouse on the embedded system normally,different from linux? and how can i change the configuration so that mouse moving will not effect the focus

Comment: If that is the issue then you'll need to check the documentation for whichever window manager you're using -- they all have their own means of configuration.

Comment: What kind of embedded system?  Are you sure it's X11 and not framebuffer?  Which WM?  Mouse, touchscreen, keyboard?  And where's your [mcve]?

Comment: @TobySpeight i don't know what kind of  embedded, i worked on it few days. it's x11 without WM(may be), and has mouse,keyboard,when start the machine,you will see a QSplashScreen,then the mainwindow.

Comment: If you have no window manager, than that's to be expected - focus follows mouse.  You'll want to install a lightweight window manager (and configure it to not add decorations to windows).  I've recently used **pekwm** for an embedded application where I needed some hotkeys as well as focus management - if you need help with configuring the WM, you'll need to head over to [su] or [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it is behaving this way. However, you may try setting setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus) for the QPushButton if you don't need tab focus for the button.

Comment: this is a example,in fact,this happend in a complex application,so i have to find out the reason.